# How to say "better+verb"

Tags: grammar, syntax

If one wanted to say >subject+better+verb, how would you say that. Would ほうがいい work？

Comment: Could you clarify the meaning with an example? I'm guessing the idea is something like "I'd better go soon" or "She'd better start searching now."

Comment: "You better leave me alone"....that type of context (along the lines of "ought")

Comment: in case of that, then there is no politeness needed, therefore you can say どいて！ 放っといて！一人にしてくれ！etc.

Answer (score 3):

Several options, depending on your needs:

1. ～たほうがいい: better to do this (rather than to do that)
2. ～する＋べき: should do this (aka better do this )
3. ～ればいい: if you do this, it would be good/better
4. ～れば幸い: I would be happy if you can do this ( for me )

Comment: ～るほうがいい can be used as well (though more rarely).