# Meaning of 乗ったほうがいい

Tags: grammar, syntax

I couldn't understand 乗ったほう, I would like an explanation about this construction.

> このバスに**乗ったほう**がいいですよ。

Comment: Related? -> http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/37157/9831  ・  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24426/9831  ・  http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3630/9831

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The grammar construction in this case V.た+方{ほう}がいい.

It means "it'd be better to, had better, should". Another example:

> 学校に行く前に何か食べたほうがいいです。