# What does しておいたほうがいい mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, words

I was reading the sentence:
'大勢でレストランへ行く時は、前もって予約を**しておいたほうがいい**と思う。' ,
but I have not understood what this expression means.

Comment: Maybe http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41435/7810 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

〜しておく means to do something in advance.

EDIT: So the sentence can be translated as "When going to a restaurant with a large group of people, you should make a reservation ahead of time."

Comment: Where do you get "a crowded (popular) restaurant" from?

Comment: It is taken from: '大勢でレストラン'.

Comment: I think @l'électeur's point is that 大勢でレストランへ行く時は means 'When large numbers of people go to a restaurant' i.e. when you go as a big group it's better to make a resevation. It doesn't mean that there are a lot of people **at** the restaurant.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. I misread the sentence :-)

Comment: But the ideia of doing in advance is not already transmitted by '前もって'?

Answer (score 2):

In your sentence 「～しておく」 means to do something in preparation for another purpose.  "Do" it and "put" it aside for later use.  Therefore often used in the phrase[「準備しておく」](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E6%BA%96%E5%82%99%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8A%E3%81%8F) meaning "get ready in advance；prepare in advance".  As for [「ほうがいい」](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41435/7810) - broken headphones reference.

Together - "you had better make a reservation (first, in advance)"

Note:  「しておく」 is to also used in the continous sense to mean　"to keep, to maintain" as in 「清潔にしておく」→　"to keep clean, to maintain clean condition"

Comment: But the ideia of doing in advance is not already transmitted by '前もって'?